# Empty row doing insert

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I have tried to enter a record with a new table and the below message shows:

"Input string was not in a correct format."

Here is my code:

```
Dim max_ As String = "select MAX(referance_number) from table"
Dim obj_ As New DATAAccess
Dim ds_ As New Data.DataSet
obj_.populate_dataset_Access_accdb_test(ds_, max_)
Dim ref As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(ds_.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString)
ref = ref + 1
```

Table columns are int with not null.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is empty then the MAX will return NULL.  That means your DataRow will contain DBNull.Value, whose ToString method returns String.Empty, which obviously can't be converted to an Integer.  Test for NULL first using the DataRow's own IsNull method.

Of course, you could always do as many thousands of developers the world over do and let the database generated sequential IDs for you.

Comment: I would recommend using an auto number field as suggested by jmcihinney. If you have multiple users creating records there could be a time when two or more users will be trying to create a record using the same ID. Example User1 gets the next ID waits for a while, meanwhile User2 makes a request for the max number and gets the same ID as User1 has not created his record... User1 creates their record and then User2 gets an error.